# Symfony/doctrine using multiple groups in query but can't access the grouped objects

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, group-by

I have a query that's grouping the table Workhours by the entities(foreign keys) User and Jobs. The idea is to get a sum of all workhours where the same user object and Jobs objects are entered into workhours.

The query is getting the exact results i am after, but i can't access the jobs entity or user entity that its grouped by. At the moment i am suming the jobs id and dividing it by the count just to find out the Job Id which is very impractical.

```
SELECT count(w) as total, j,w, sum(w.jobs) as jobid, sum(w.minutesWorked) as Hours
FROM   ProjectBundle:WorkHours w
join w.jobs j
join w.user u
where w.jobs is not null            

group by w.user, w.jobs
```

Not sure why i can't access the object like normal if for example it was only grouped by user. Any help would be appreciated.

Edited - First row of data produced by the var  dump

```
1 => array:9 [▼
    0 => WorkHours {#654 ▼
      -id: 1229
      -user: User {#646 …30}
      -hoursWork: DateTime {#657 …3}
      -dateWorked: DateTime {#656 …3}
      -dateRecorded: DateTime {#655 …3}
      -jobs: Jobs {#647 …11}
       #hourApprove: null
      -scope: Scope {#535 …5}
       #minutesWorked: 90

      #totalCharged: "20250.00"
    }
    "total" => "2"
    "jobid" => "1590"
    "hours" => "190"
```

Comment: Can you post the results that you are actually seeing, and how you are trying to access?

Comment: Edited the question. Trying to access using twig {{ 0.WorkHours.Jobs.Id }}

Comment: Please post code of what variable you are saving the data to, and also take a look at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results